# MetaUML Adds Extra Vertical Spaces

Tags: pdftex, metapost, metauml

MetaUML seems to add extra vertical space to the class members.

[image: MetaUML]

As you can see only the fourth and fifth elements are aligned properly. The image was generated by pdflatex using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[shellescape, latex]{gmp}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{mpost}[mpsettings = input metauml;]
    Class.Test("Test")
    (
      "-dasa:int",
      "-ds:int",
      "-dsdasdassd:int",
      "-dlasjdladjslas:int",
      "-djkkd:int",
      "-ds:int",
      "-dasdasdas:int"
    )
    (
    );
    drawObjects(Test);
  \end{mpost}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: I notice that the "correct" lines are the only ones with descenders (the j characters) this looks like some feature/bug in metauml.  If you replace all the `j` characters with (say) `z`s then the spacing is regular. Clearly it *should* work nicely for any contents

Comment: I am sure this is not the *right* answer, but the labels are processed as TeX so you could just add `\strut` to the end of each string like this: `"-ds:int\strut"`

But I hope someone from MetaUML will answer properly

Comment: @Thruston doesn’t work. I get int\protect \relax \unhcopy \strutbox. Do you know how I can force it to expand properly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work around using an improvement on my `\strut` suggestion that appears to work ok with `luamplib` and `lualatex` which provide a simpler and better integrated access to Metapost.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\everymplib{input metauml; beginfig(0);}
\everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    Class.Test("Test")
    (
      "-dasa:int \phantom{)}",
      "-ds:int \phantom{)}",
      "-dsdasdassd:int \phantom{)}",
      "-dlasjdladjslas:int \phantom{)}",
      "-djkkd:int \phantom{)}",
      "-ds:int \phantom{)}",
      "-dasdasdas:int \phantom{)}"
    )
    (
    );
    drawObjects(Test);
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `lualatex` produces this output (with properly spaced lines).

[image]

Comment: I believe that `\vphantom{)}` is the underlying definition of `\strut`, so it should be clear what correction should be made to the package assumptions.