# How do I use LaTeX commands inside the body of mpost? (metauml + gmp)

Tags: metapost, metauml

I am on Overleaf, using gmp + metauml to create a UML class diagram, in which I wish to use LaTeX commands to better format the text. I tried my best to read the manuals for both packages and scour through TeX.SE but cannot find a way.

Specifically, I wish to use the `\vphantom{}` comamnd to better format the attributes of a class and fix the problem presented in [MetaUML Adds Extra Vertical Spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596581/metauml-adds-extra-vertical-spaces).

Attempting to use `\textbf{}` with

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}

\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}[mpsettings={input metauml;}]
    beginfig(1);
        Class.subject("Subject")("-test:\textbf{h}")(static "+attach(o : Observer)");
        drawObjects(subject);
    endfig;
    end
\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

results in expansion of the command as shown below:

[image]

Attempting to use `\vphantom{}` results in output

[image]

and errors:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you can use TeX macros in a metauml picture? By the way, you shouldn't have `end` in the `mpost` environment.

Comment: @egreg You're right, it turned out that I cannot use TeX macros in metauml. Thank you for the pointers. Accepting Thruston's answer as it provides a suitable working alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have better luck using `lualatex` and `luamplib`.  Here is your example reworked for that environment.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input metauml
beginfig(1);
Class.subject("Subject")("-test:\textbf{h}")(static "+attach(o : Observer)");
drawObjects(subject);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

compiling this with `lualatex` produces this:

[image]

Note that you have to explicitly set the font to Times (or equivalent) at the document level, and that you need to have `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` set so that all labels are automagically processed with the `TEX()` macro.

Note also that Overleaf has an option (menu top left) to change the compiler to `lualatex`.  And I can confirm that the reworked example I show, produces the same output there.